# Iframe enter fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to make iframe enter fullscreen mode,
i am using iframe to display pdf file by google docs viewer
i need this iframe to enter fullscreen.
I have found an code in the internet for displaying html video and iframe and there full screen but when i try to remove the video, the fullscreen never work
In this code the iframe (fullscreen) not working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_styles.css" media="screen">

<title>Fullscreen API | The CSS Ninja</title>
```

```
<div class="fl">
    <iframe src="http://thecssninja.com/talks/dnd_and_friends/" width="320" height="240" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe><br /> 
    <button id="fullscreeniframe" class="button">Fullscreen iframe</button>
</div>

<script>
    (function(window, document){
        var $ = function(selector,context){return(context||document).querySelector(selector)};

        var video  = $("video"),
            iframe = $("iframe"),
            domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' ');

        var fullscreen = function(elem) {
            var prefix;
            // Mozilla and webkit intialise fullscreen slightly differently
            for ( var i = -1, len = domPrefixes.length; ++i < len; ) {
              prefix = domPrefixes[i].toLowerCase();

              if ( elem[prefix + 'EnterFullScreen'] ) {
                // Webkit uses EnterFullScreen for video
                return prefix + 'EnterFullScreen';
                break;
              } else if( elem[prefix + 'RequestFullScreen'] ) {
                // Mozilla uses RequestFullScreen for all elements and webkit uses it for non video elements
                return prefix + 'RequestFullScreen';
                break;
              }
            }

            return false;
        };

        // Will return fullscreen method as a string if supported e.g. "mozRequestFullScreen" || false;
        var fullscreenvideo = fullscreen(document.createElement("video"));

        // Webkit uses "requestFullScreen" for non video elements
        var fullscreenother = fullscreen(document.createElement("iframe"));

        if(!fullscreen) {
            alert("Fullscreen won't work, please make sure you're using a browser that supports it and you have enabled the feature");
            return;
        }

        // Should add prefixed events for potential ms/o or unprefixed support too
        video.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange",function(){
            console.log(document.webkitIsFullScreen);
        }, false);
        video.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange",function(){
            console.log(document.mozFullScreen);
        }, false);

        $("#fullscreenvid").addEventListener("click", function(){
            // The test returns a string so we can easily call it on a click event
            video[fullscreenvideo]();
        }, false);
        $("#fullscreeniframe").addEventListener("click", function(){
            // iframe fullscreen and non video elements in webkit use request over enter
            iframe[fullscreenother]();
        }, false);
    })(this, this.document);
</script>
```

http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/fullscreen/

Comment: any error in console? What do you mean by: "when i try to remove the video"? I still see a video tag in your posted code

Comment: this code i got it from the file, when i try to remove the video tag <div> the iframe fullscreen is not working

Comment: so the code which is not working is not the code you have posted?

Comment: yes, now i edit the code which is not working

Comment: Let me ask you again: any error in console???  Don't just say "it's not working" because that's not really helpfull...

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean by (any error in console?)

Comment: all modern browsers have a console, press F12 in you browser to open the console. Reload your page (F5) then see if any error appear (tab console). If any message, please post it, this is the easiest way to catch any error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: thank you for that i have corrected  the error

Comment: Glad you have fixed it! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've removed video references, try that:

```
(function(window, document){
        var $ = function(selector,context){return(context||document).querySelector(selector)};

        var iframe = $("iframe"),
            domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' ');

        var fullscreen = function(elem) {
            var prefix;
            // Mozilla and webkit intialise fullscreen slightly differently
            for ( var i = -1, len = domPrefixes.length; ++i < len; ) {
              prefix = domPrefixes[i].toLowerCase();

              if ( elem[prefix + 'EnterFullScreen'] ) {
                // Webkit uses EnterFullScreen for video
                return prefix + 'EnterFullScreen';
                break;
              } else if( elem[prefix + 'RequestFullScreen'] ) {
                // Mozilla uses RequestFullScreen for all elements and webkit uses it for non video elements
                return prefix + 'RequestFullScreen';
                break;
              }
            }

            return false;
        };              
        // Webkit uses "requestFullScreen" for non video elements
        var fullscreenother = fullscreen(document.createElement("iframe"));

        if(!fullscreen) {
            alert("Fullscreen won't work, please make sure you're using a browser that supports it and you have enabled the feature");
            return;
        }

        $("#fullscreeniframe").addEventListener("click", function(){
            // iframe fullscreen and non video elements in webkit use request over enter
            iframe[fullscreenother]();
        }, false);
    })(this, this.document);
```

Comment: in next time i will use consule it is helpful

Comment: Hi, in Chrome Version 86.0.4240.75 Esc is not working sometimes to exit the full screen after entering the full screen mode.

Comment: It means after entering into full screen mode then I clicked inside the pdf, in this situation the ESC is not returning to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have extended the solution provided by @A.Wolff , I have added a button within the Iframe
you can check the solution right here on w3

[Full screen toogle with inside/internal button| W3](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GOJQVFGKAM7D)

Regards

Comment: good example but how to exit full screen with same button